# Inserting into new Table getting more records, CROSS JOIN, UPDATE

Tags: sql-server, ssms

In my current data structure my `OFFENSE` table doesnt have all the columns that I need. For this reason I inner join it with several other table columns and insert it into a new table called `TexasCCHPublicRecords` created by me. This is my query:

```
INSERT INTO TexasCCHPublicRecords (OFF_IDN, TRS_IDN, AGY_TXT, DOO_DTE, AON_COD, AOL_TXT, LDA_CODE, GOC_COD, ADN_COD, ADD_TXT, ADA_DTE, REF_TXT, 
IPN_NBR, ICA_NBR, DMV_COD, TRS_CODE, TRN_CODE, PERSON_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, DATE_OF_BIRTH, CDN, OffenseCode, OffenseName, CDNCode, ArrestingAgency,
ArrestingAgencyORI, ProsecutionAgency, ProsecutionAgencyORI)

SELECT o.* , trs.TRS_COD as 'TRS_CODE', trn.TRN_NBR as 'TRN_CODE', p.PER_IDN as 'PERSON_ID', nam.FNA_TXT as 'FIRST_NAME', nam.LNA_TXT as 'LAST_NAME', 
birth.DOB_DTE as 'DATE_OF_BIRTH', cdnCode.CDN_VAL_TXT as 'CDN', offenseCode.OFF_COD as 'OffenseCode', offenseCode.LIT_TXT as 'OffenseName', 
cdnCode.CDN_VAL_COD as 'CDNCode', arrestingAgency.ATR_TXT as 'ArrestingAgency', arrestingAgency.ORI_TXT as 'ArrestingAgencyORI', 
prosecutionAgency.ATR_TXT as 'ProsecutionAgency',prosecutionAgency.ORI_TXT as 'ProsecutionAgencyORI'
    FROM OFFENSE o
    inner join CCH_PUBLIC.dbo.TRS  trs on trs.TRS_IDN = o.TRS_IDN 
    inner join CCH_PUBLIC.dbo.TRN  trn on trn.TRN_IDN = trs.TRN_IDN 
    inner join CCH_PUBLIC.dbo.PERSON  p on p.IND_IDN = trn .IND_IDN 
    inner join CCH_PUBLIC.dbo.NAME nam on nam.PER_IDN = p.PER_IDN
    inner join CCH_PUBLIC.dbo.BRTHDATE birth on birth.PER_IDN = p.PER_IDN
    inner join CCH_PUBLIC.dbo.PROSECUTION prose on prose.TRS_IDN = o.TRS_IDN
    inner join CCH_PUBLIC.dbo.AGENCY arrestingAgency on arrestingAgency.ORI_TXT = o.AGY_TXT
    inner join CCH_PUBLIC.dbo.AGENCY prosecutionAgency on prosecutionAgency.ORI_TXT = o.REF_TXT
    inner join CCH_PUBLIC.dbo.CRT_STAT crtStat on crtStat.TRS_IDN = o.TRS_IDN
    inner join CCH_PUBLIC.dbo.CDN_COD cdnCode on cdnCode.CDN_VAL_COD = crtStat.CDN_COD
    inner join CCH_PUBLIC.dbo.OFF_CODE offenseCode on offenseCode.OFF_COD = o.AON_COD
```

I would conclude that this table would select every offense in the `OFFENSE` table inner join it with the other tables and insert it into the `TexasCCHPublicRecords`

However after running this simple count

```
select count(*) as 'Offense Table Record Count' FROM OFFENSE
select count(*) as 'CCHPublicRecords Table Record Count' FROM TexasCCHPublicRecords
```

I end with these results:

```
Offense Table Record Count
11372377

CCHPublicRecords Table Record Count
49666836
```

There are 38 million more records in my new table. How did this happen? Is my query inserting repeated instances of the same offense row?

My goal is to SELECT an OFFENSE inner join it with the tables that are associated with it and INSERT that into my empty table. What am i doing wrong?

> UPDATE

After reading one of the comments I realized that one of the tables was giving me 7 columns. Now I am trying to ONLY select the FIRST result. I am trying to do a CROSS APPLY however I am not sure what to place on the outside of the cross apply. This is my select Query:

```
SELECT o.*, trs.TRS_COD as 'TRS_CODE', trn.TRN_NBR as 'TRN_CODE', p.PER_IDN as 'PERSON_ID', nam.FNA_TXT as 'FIRST_NAME', nam.LNA_TXT as 'LAST_NAME', 
birth.DOB_DTE as 'DATE_OF_BIRTH', cdnCode.CDN_VAL_TXT as 'CDN', offenseCode.OFF_COD as 'OffenseCode', offenseCode.LIT_TXT as 'OffenseName', 
cdnCode.CDN_VAL_COD as 'CDNCode', arrestingAgency.ATR_TXT as 'ArrestingAgency', arrestingAgency.ORI_TXT as 'ArrestingAgencyORI', 
prosecutionAgency.ATR_TXT as 'ProsecutionAgency',prosecutionAgency.ORI_TXT as 'ProsecutionAgencyORI'
    FROM OFFENSE o
    inner join CCH_PUBLIC.dbo.TRS  trs on trs.TRS_IDN = o.TRS_IDN 
    inner join CCH_PUBLIC.dbo.TRN  trn on trn.TRN_IDN = trs.TRN_IDN 
    inner join CCH_PUBLIC.dbo.PERSON  p on p.IND_IDN = trn.IND_IDN 
    inner join CCH_PUBLIC.dbo.BRTHDATE birth on birth.PER_IDN = p.PER_IDN
    inner join CCH_PUBLIC.dbo.PROSECUTION prose on prose.TRS_IDN = o.TRS_IDN
    inner join CCH_PUBLIC.dbo.AGENCY arrestingAgency on arrestingAgency.ORI_TXT = o.AGY_TXT
    inner join CCH_PUBLIC.dbo.AGENCY prosecutionAgency on prosecutionAgency.ORI_TXT = o.REF_TXT
    inner join CCH_PUBLIC.dbo.CRT_STAT crtStat on crtStat.TRS_IDN = o.TRS_IDN
    inner join CCH_PUBLIC.dbo.CDN_COD cdnCode on cdnCode.CDN_VAL_COD = crtStat.CDN_COD
    inner join CCH_PUBLIC.dbo.OFF_CODE offenseCode on offenseCode.OFF_COD = o.AON_COD
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT TOP 1 *
        FROM CCH_PUBLIC.dbo.NAME as nam
        WHERE nam.PER_IDN = p.PER_IDN
    ) nam
```

is the `nam` out of the CROSS APPLY correct?

Comment: Obviously one or more of your joins is matching on more than 1 row.

Comment: Thanks I will look into it. @SeanLange

Comment: you probably joined a master table with a child table causing it to return every match in the child table. Start with a child table and join upwards from there